# PHP Slim - how to have multiple app objects for different routes?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, slim

Is it possible to have multiple Slim application objects for different sections/routes of a website.

For example:

- */api* -> having its own Slim object with its own routes, configs etc.
- */admin-panel* -> having its own Slim objects (maybe with some middleware)

I already tried modifing **Apache's .htaccess** using:

```
RewriteRule ^api front_controller_api.inc.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin-panel front_controller_admin.inc.php [QSA,L]
```

...but this seems to break Slim's routing principles because Slim thinks that */api* and */admin-panel* are part of the request URI. It would be much easier to have different app objects with different configurations, middlewares etc. for each section of a page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if that's the correct way to do it, but you try a folder structure like this:

```
public/
|-> api/
    |-> index.php
    |-> .htaccess
|-> admin-panel/
    |-> index.php
    |-> .htaccess
```

**UPDATE:**

I "investigated" some more and came up with another solution:

```
public/
|-> .htaccess
|-> admin-panel.php
|-> api.php
```

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin-panel/ admin-panel.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/ api.php [QSA,L]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

With this solution you have to group everything to `'/admin-panel'` or `'/api'` in your route defintion.

Comment: That sounds good and seems to work. However I have to test what happens if I use a htaccess within the public/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a easy way using [groups](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/groups/):

```
$app->group('/api', function () use ($app){
    //Your api scope
    $app->myCustom = "my custom";

    $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        echo $app->myCustom;
    });

});

//Your amazing middleware.
function adminPanelMiddleware() {
    echo "This is my custom middleware!<br/>";
}


$app->group('/admin-panel', 'adminPanelMiddleware', function () use ($app){
    //Your admin-panel scope
    $app->anotherCustom = "another custom";

    $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        echo $app->anotherCustom;
    });
});
```

Comment: Well I know the grouping-system but I tried to avoid it because both parts of my page are too different to use the same $app object.